Why do I hear crackling sounds on Ubuntu 24.04? How can I fix it?
I have recently switched over to Ubuntu 24.04 and I hear crackling sounds more often why is it and how can I fix it?

The likely issue for crackling sounds on Ubuntu 24.04 is that the distro has been switching over to pipewire and it runs a conversion service from pulse audio, namely pipewire-pulse.
The challenge is that many apps don't directly talk to piepewire, but do it through JACK and/or especially pulse itself, hence sound data needs to be moved though additional hops.
The default time buffers for pipewire-pulse is 2.7 ms, which means that an application needs to be able to fill sound content every 2.7 ms, otherwise pipewire will send to the audio device whatever was previously filled and potentially some random data, hence the crackling.
2.7 ms is quite a stringent time, especially for applications which don't have dedicated threads for audio (likely Proton/wine/games) and/or when running on old CPUs - hence one way to limit cracking is to tell pipewire-pulse to set a larger time buffer, albeit adding a delay to when the sound is sent to the audio device.
In order to do so, one needs to open the file:
/usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf
And then find, uncomment and change the configuration for the item:
pulse.min.quantum      = 128/48000     # 2.7ms

from he value 128 to something larger - one should try 256 or even 512 as a starting point and if they experience no crackling they should leave as is (please note that after saving the file, one has to restart pipewire, pipewire-pulse via systemctl --user restart wireplumber pipewire pipewire-pulse).
The key is to find the smallest number so that the annoying crackling is not present (or at an acceptable minimum), because if larger numbers (such as 1024) make very little crackling happen, they add a delay (1024 / 48000 -> 21.333 ms).
Slower CPUs will need numbers as 512 or higher, or when using multiple software keeping the CPU busy, it's likely that a number such as 1024 or even 2048 may be beneficial.
Please note that crackling is by default (128/48000) noticeable on a 5950x (32 cores/16 threads) with 64 GiB of ram, hence it's likely much more noticeable on less powerful CPUs.
As a side note, not sure why/how Canonical/Ubuntu have decided to ship this stringent config, looking at how many threads complaining about crackling are pervasive on this forum and others.

Can you qualify "Please note that crackling is by default (128/48000) noticeable on a 5950x (32 cores/16 threads) with 64 GiB of ram, hence it's likely much more noticeable on less powerful CPUs." How do you know? Like you said, it seems stringent, and with those numbers, nowhere near realistic.

Note that as mentioned in that file, one is supposed to make a custom version in /etc/pipewire or ~/.config/pipewire rather than editing /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf.

@ysalmon, Works, ref: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/1d1ef61/pipewire_audio_distortion_and_crackling_fix/
but temporarily, jumping back/forward in a video playback the noise comes back.

solution doesn't fully fix the problem. Still very annoying.

Tried step by step up to 2056 and didn't work… (Intel i7 7thGen laptop)

Finding this setting to 2048 may have solved it for me... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1514900/ubuntu-24-04-sound-issues-zoom-lenovo-ideapad-laptop

"And then find, uncomment and change the configuration for the item:" Right here is where a screenshot would have been nice cause I'm not sure what exactly you're talking about here, I'm a newbie and I get so confused with this stuff. I'm a visual learner so please take a screenshot so I can see what it is you're talking about. Man this stuff is just so complicated to me. I'm a newbie and I can't understand what to do here. I need screenshots. I'm a visual learner.

@James1 Lines in a system file with a # as the first character indicate a comment. You just delete the character to make the line active and follow the other instructions provided.

@graham You computer experts seem to forget that the vast majority of PC users really only know how to turn on a PC and open up a web browser and browse the web and that's it. Your average PC user wouldn't even know what a "command line" is. I am your average PC user and I need to see screenshots, I'm a visual learner, don't tell me, just take a screenshot and show me. Please walk me through this step by step? You coders and programmers need to remember, most PC users are dumb compared to you.

I'm an average PC user just like you. Time to learn like we all had to do in the beginning of our Linux journey. I gave you a link to understand how to use Nano earlier. If you use Nano without sudo privileges , you will be able to see the file without altering it which might increase your confidence. Make a backup of important data and be prepared to reinstall Ubuntu if you brick your system. It's good learning practice  Bonne chance!

I searched again for kernel 6.8 and ati sound issues , i read this https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=294114
and run these commands
wpctl clear-default  
systemctl restart --user pipewire

So far it seems to have resolved the issue.
Others in this forum post agree , something to do with wireplumber.
10 mins after still no issues with sound on videos , checked also the HDMI output.
UPDATE: Unfortunatelly , after 1 day problem appeared again.

Thanks, This works, but temporarily only. Jumping forward or return in a video (Youtube or anything else) the noise comes back. It also happens wen starting/restarrting skype and also making a screendump (after the camera sound)

This seems to have worked in my case, at least for a short term - still testing it. I had an issue where the sound was fine until I connected bluetooth earbuds (technics eah-az80), then system switches to the earbuds and on the earbuds you can hear the music desynchronizing, crackling and then stopping - no more audio output goes through the headphones. The only solution was to 2x change the configuration in the Settings - Sound - Configuration dropdown to the chosen profile. I'll test this solution a bit more. Thanks!

Driving me bonkers. I tried pulse.min.quantum changes but it didn't work. I've just tried this solution here and confirm this worked for me (for now). Will see how long for

No still having me the same issue.. :(

The accepted answer from @Emanuele works for me on Linux Mint 22 (Ubuntu 24.04).
It's surprising that it has 0 votes. Due to not enough 50 reputations, I cannot comment or upvote, so I am writing this here so that others know the solution is worth trying.
I created a small script to automate the solution:
# copy the default config to `/etc/pipewire` for editing
export newConf=/etc/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf
sudo mkdir -p $(dirname $newConf)
sudo cp /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf $newConf

# uncomment and change the value from 128 to 1024
sudo sed -i.bak 's/#pulse.min.quantum      = 128\/48000     # 2.7ms/pulse.min.quantum      = 1024\/48000/' $newConf

# check if the sed command successfully changed the config, log should show 1024
cat $newConf | grep "pulse.min.quantum"

# after changing the config, restart the audio services
systemctl --user restart wireplumber pipewire pipewire-pulse
# I restart the computer too


Tung Dao Thanh Tung How do I do this exactly? I'm a newbie I'm not sure what to do here, so do I just copy all that script and paste it as is into my terminal and hit enter?

@James1 yes, you do copy to the terminal and enter, it will ask you for password for sudo, because it needs to creates a config file in /usr/share/

In Ubuntu 24.04 (at least) there is now a utility "Ubuntu Studio Audio configuration" For me 48000 512 with external USB 2.0 audio interface worked. You can could also try install low latency kernel to get lower latency
Well, it works sort of... when going back or forward in videos the noise is coming back.

The problem is caused by the kernel 6.8. Downgrading to previous version solves it.

Just compiled  kernel 6.12-rc1 with the new feature REALTIME kernel. It is stable and it reduces latency from 1024 to 256. 128 sample size is causing distortion. It's a bit better but it's still probably and best case  16msec latency (assume it's 3 buffers, can't tell) which is still unacceptable for audio production. (that is a direct monitoring headphone on the USB device will have a significant difference versus the audio from the USB host). and it still often come back making a screenshot or jumping forward or back while a playing video. 9using a USB 2.0 audio interface)
24.10 same result. (PREEMPT_REALTIME and PREEMPT_DYNAMIC)

I was on Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.10 with kernel up to 6.11 w/o cracking problems. The problem started after exactly after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04. The tool helps once, but the pause a Youtube video and start again or making s screendump(camera sound) the cracking noise comes back again. PW may work for on board CODECS but external usb audio devices seems not well supported, in the past 10 years before PW, could run 5 to 8 msec with 3 buffers in Jack2. Now it needs at least 512 bytes. I am running the Pro audio profile.
Also when I switch on my USB interface while Ubuntu is running it does not see the device. No one else has PW issues like these ? Is there any issues tracking this ?

Just restart PW, seems to be enough. The key question why does this happen with PW and not Jack/Pulse audio and specially starting with  24.04 ? Ubuntu 24.10 has the  same result.

I already had the cracking on Ubuntu 23.10. Pipewire is the fault.

Kernel 6.13 seems to solve this issue. No more noise on the USB audio interface. :-)
