How exactly do I edit /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf?
So I'm on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and the sound was working just fine for many weeks and then about 2 weeks ago the sound just started acting funny, I can hear the sound and I can make out what people are saying but it's crackly, it's got static noise in it. If I remember correctly about 2 weeks ago there was an update and then my sound started acting funny so I believe an update to Ubuntu is what caused this, though I'm not sure.
I've been trying to fix this on my own and nothing has worked. So yeah I've tried a couple of solutions already and it hasn't worked.
But I've found this thread here Why do I hear crackling sounds on Ubuntu 24.04? How can I fix it? and I want to try Emanuele's solution but I'm a little confused.
So in Nautilus file manager you need to go into "Other Locations" (which you'll see under Trash) to be able to find the folder /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf I need to specify this part cause at first I couldn't find this folder cause I was looking in my Home folder, if I got confused here then surely other people did as well.
Ok so here's where I'm not sure what to do exactly, I know Emanuele tells you what to do but I'm a newbie here, I really do need someone to hold my hand and walk me through this step by step. Will someone explain this to me like I'm 5?
I really do appreciate screenshots too, I'm a visual learner. Well, I can learn from text sure, but screenshots really do help though.
Please create instructions with screenshots that are easy for the average layman to understand? Thank you.
Edit: Also on this page Why do I hear crackling sounds on Ubuntu 24.04? How can I fix it? you'll see that Tung Dao Thanh Tung has created a script to automate the process. This is his script
# copy the default config to `/etc/pipewire` for editing
export newConf=/etc/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf
sudo mkdir -p $(dirname $newConf)
sudo cp /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf $newConf

# uncomment and change the value from 128 to 1024
sudo sed -i.bak 's/#pulse.min.quantum      = 128\/48000     # 2.7ms/pulse.min.quantum      = 1024\/48000/' $newConf

# check if the sed command successfully changed the config, log should show 1024
cat $newConf | grep "pulse.min.quantum"

# after changing the config, restart the audio services
systemctl --user restart wireplumber pipewire pipewire-pulse
# I restart the computer too

So yeah I'm a newbie so how exactly do I do this, do I just copy all that text and paste it as is into my terminal and hit enter, is that what I do?
I mean if I could just use a script instead of having to use a text editor (I've literally never ever had to use nano or any text editor before, I've only been using Linux for about 3 years now) that would be excellent.
So you're supposed to set the value from 128 to 1024
but Amos Folarin said that he changed 128 to 2048 and that's what worked for him. And I'm assuming that I could implement this change in the script as well, you know just edit the script slightly, like this for example
# copy the default config to `/etc/pipewire` for editing
export newConf=/etc/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf
sudo mkdir -p $(dirname $newConf)
sudo cp /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf $newConf

# uncomment and change the value from 128 to 2048
sudo sed -i.bak 's/#pulse.min.quantum      = 128\/48000     # 2.7ms/pulse.min.quantum      = 2048\/48000/' $newConf

# check if the sed command successfully changed the config, log should show 2048
cat $newConf | grep "pulse.min.quantum"

# after changing the config, restart the audio services
systemctl --user restart wireplumber pipewire pipewire-pulse
# I restart the computer too

Notice the three little edits in there to 2048? So I made a total of three edits to the script (where it said 1024, I changed it to 2048), but would this work?
I mean if I can use a simple script to do this that'd be much more user friendly.
Or if I need to use nano and edit the file, well I've never used nano before so please could you create step by step instructions that your average computer user can follow? I'm not a coder or programmer, please someone hold my hand and walk me through this? If I don't have detailed step by step instructions that tell me exactly what to do then I will get confused.
Edit: For instance @ysalmon says "Note that as mentioned in that file, one is supposed to make a custom version in /etc/pipewire or ~/.config/pipewire rather than editing /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf."
I'm sitting here scratching my head going "So what am I supposed to do exactly?" Can someone walk me through this, please?
I haven't had sound in 2 weeks now. I'm desperate to get this finally fixed.

you are barking up the wrong tree. What you should do is open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and use sudo nano /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf to edit the file following the instructions given in the linked accepted answer. This will open the nano editor after which you can use the menu options shown at the foot of the window to write out the file (Ctrl+O) after which you can exit Nona using Ctrl+X how to use Nano

@graham I'm sorry this stuff really is very confusing to me. Please sir can you create an answer to my question and just walk me through this step by step? Pretty please?

Use a live USB Try Ubuntu session to experiment with the file using nano which will help you with your learning experience and save you from bricking your existing installation. Follow the instructions given in your linked answer. We all had to begin somewhere. Make sure you have good backups of important stuff before experimenting.

Your biggest problem with asking someone to provide detailed images of how to access the file and step by step instructions is that, in reading all the comments, there appears no definitive answer as different values have to be used to get the result required dependant on the hardware. I am not using 24.04 (nor the same hardware as you (probably) so the only thing that can be usefully done is to guide you through the process of accessing and amending the file using the default nano text editor as described by the accepted linked answer. Sorry if that seems a tad harsh but it's the way it is.

@graham Will you check out the new edits to my post? I really do need a Linux expert to create a step by step tutorial I can follow. Please is that really too much to ask? Please isn't there someone here who can make a step by step tutorial for us newbies to follow?

@graham I wanna pull my hair out I really do. I can't figure this out.

you might benefit from reading this Ask Ubuntu Q&A on using the nano text editor

How exactly do I edit /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf?
Right:
Open a terminal.
Run in it:
sudo cp /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf.res

With this command you copy the file /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf to /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf.res
If you want to restore it, you restore it with this command:
sudo cp /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf.res /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf

Once the backup is done, you edit it with this command in the same terminal:
sudo nano /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf

In the file that opens, you look for the characters you want to change, you change them and with Ctrl + O, you save the file, with Ctrl + X, you close nano and with the following command in the same terminal you restart the system, to see if The changes are effective on your sound system:
sudo reboot


With recent versions of nano Ctrl+S saves the file as well without the need for hitting the Enter key. I find this more intuitive.

Save without asking, something risky for a user who doesn't know it.

I guess you always choose "Save As..." in a GUI app and never click the "Save"  button. That's fine.

So I am editing the backup to be exact? So I'm editing /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf.res? Why didn't you name the backup file /etc/pipewire ? I'm just curious why you're doing it a little different?

Wait a second which file am I editing exactly, /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf or /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf.res ? I thought we weren't supposed to edit /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf ? Well that's what @ysalmon says on this page here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1525336/why-do-i-hear-crackling-sounds-on-ubuntu-24-04-how-can-i-fix-it

The question is: How exactly do I edit /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf? . And the answer is: How exactly do you edit /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf. sudo nano /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf, edits precisely /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf and not /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf.res

@kyodake I'm trying to fix my sound issue and you know that, you know that right? Anyhow you're telling me to edit /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf directly and @ysalmon here is saying not to do that (you'll find ysalmon's comment under Emanuele's answer) https://askubuntu.com/questions/1525336/why-do-i-hear-crackling-sounds-on-ubuntu-24-04-how-can-i-fix-it Now if it is ok to directly edit /usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf then please just say so?

You don't say what your sound card is. You don't say which files you have sound problems with.You don't say which application the sound problems occur with. You don't say if they are sound or video files. You don't say if the files are local, on the network or on the web.  It only says that you have decided to edit the pipewire-pulse.conf file. And how to do it was the answer this was. Apparently all sound issues are attributed to the 6.8 kernel, so downgrading to the previous version should fix it.
